# Elegant way to print a binary tree vertically in C++

Tags: c++, tree

It's easier to print a tree horizontally. A simple preorder traversal would do, for example:

```
└── 1
    ├── 6
    │   ├── *
    │   └── 4
    │       ├── 5
    │       └── 2
    │           ├── 3
    │           └── *
    └── 0
```

And an elegant implementation would look like this:

```
void print(Node* node, string indent, bool is_tail) {
  cout << indent << (is_tail ? "└── " : "├── ");
  if (node == nullptr) {
    cout << "*" << endl;
    return;
  }
  cout << node->val << endl;
  if (node->left != nullptr || node->right != nullptr) {
    indent.append(is_tail ? "    " : "│   ");
    print(node->right, indent, false);
    print(node->left, indent, true);
  }
}
```

However, the code printing a tree vertically seems to be a bit cumbersome. Any idea how to print a tree like this?

```
       2               
      / \       
     /   \      
    /     \     
   /       \    
   7       5       
  / \       \   
 /   \       \  
 2   6       9   
    / \     /   
    5 8     4
```

Comment: "the code printing a tree vertically seems to be a bit cumbersome" - why don't you show the code you think's cumbersome and ask if it can be simplified...?  It doesn't make a whole lot of sense for us to go off writing a solution risking having you say "yeah, that's why I did and as I said it's a bit cumbersome...".

Comment: I have an idea, by increasing an attribute of nodes, which stores the number of nodes that less than it. actually it is the distance away from the left edge. suppose one node is bigger than its left child, less than its right child. In this case, we can get node 2 which has 0 to bigger than, node 7 has one node to bigger than, so node 5 got 2, node 6 got 3. which actually is the distance from the left edge. but i don't know how to print it one row by one row.